# How to track the select option is deselect and and grab the deselect option value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the example of the code for the scenario.

```
<select class="car" multiple name="cars">
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="honda" selected>honda</option>
     <option value="opel" selected>Opel</option>
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>
```

Suppose if deselect the honda, how would i know that this particular option is deselected and how i will grab that option value in jquery.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First add some code here. You can keep the variable(array) holding the previous values and current Values, you can compare/filter from this.

Comment: @harpal i have tried every thing . code i have to add here is the scenario. jquery not provide the any thing where we can track the option is deselect and grab the deselected option value.
like we do for checkbox " $(this).is(":checked") ". i just want to know which option i can use for that.

Comment: It's Possible with litter tricky code. First, add a unique id in each option, after that add a class selector on select, and from that selector class name, you can recognize which is selected and which is deselected. Additionally, add a class name with CSS bg color so you can visually see the deselected options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep some variables and filter out those accordingly.

and in JS, you can handle these variables in the events

Here is the snippet, Hopefully you were looking for the same.

```js
var prevValues = [];
var currentValues = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
    currentValues = $('.car').val();
})

$('.car').on('change', function() {
  prevValues = [...currentValues];
  currentValues = $('.car').val();
  let newlyAdded = currentValues.filter(x=> !prevValues.includes(x))[0];
  let newlyRemoved = prevValues.filter(x=> !currentValues.includes(x))[0];
  if(newlyAdded) {
    console.log('Added item', newlyAdded);
  }
  if( newlyRemoved) {
    console.log('Removed Item', newlyRemoved);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="car" multiple name="cars">
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="honda" selected>honda</option>
     <option value="opel" selected>Opel</option>
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>
```